# Android Gradient which varies along y axis and centred along x axis

Tags: android, android-layout, gradient

How can i draw a shape with a gradient that varies along y xis and centered along x axis with 2 colors in android?

Basically i want use this shape as a background for a layout which is right below another linear layout to achieve a shadow effect exactly at the center.

[image: shadow]

Comment: Post an image of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @Juan-devtopia.coop i have added an image.

Comment: @HemanthMalla Is that gradient varying along both the x and the y dimensions?

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike it should start with a dark color and end with light color along y axis, along x axis it should be centered ( Dark color at center)

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike any idea how such a shape can be drawn ?

Comment: @HemanthMalla Android doesn't support that directly: gradients vary along a single axis.  I do not know how to do what are trying to do, but I have suggestions: 1) try a radial gradient.  To me, that drop shadow looks almost round.  If you use a large radius, it might work.  2) try composing a gradient with a mask of varying transparency.  3) draw the shadow you want, put it in /assets, and draw it from the bitmap.

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike i tried radial gradients, but the radius was becoming either too small or too large for that effect to be visible :(